# Make windows always on top (win10)

Tags: windows-10, powershell, shell-script, window-manager, always-on-top

I know there are plenty of answers both in internet in general and in this site but none of them works for me because all involve installing some kind of software.

I would like a solution to make windows always on top without the need of installing anything. The OS is windows10. This is a feature that windows lack, so I suppose a lot of adwares and malwares will have been created as a workaround to this issue. So I am hesitant to install any executable program found online regarding this. Downloading some kind of script or source code that I can built from it the executable myself would be an ideal solution.

Comment: First you say you cannot install something to fix your problems, but then you say that you might be able to install something if it's trustworthy. First, this is not clear. Use the edit button to clarify your requirements. Second, we don't recommend software on Superuser.

Comment: Third, Windows 10 does not have this function built in and so you'll need a third party utility to do this. Fourth, what program(s) do you need to have always on top?

Comment: @music2myear I am not saying I might be able to install something if it's trustworthy, I am saying I can download (not install) script or source code to built myself. But you are right its a bit of confusing I will edit the question

Comment: @music2myear I would like for start to have always on top programs like libre office or adobe pdf viewer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From my repository at https://winsourcecode.blogspot.com/2019/05/topmostexe-set-window-on-top-or-not.html

Copy the two text files to the same folder. Their names are in the first line of both files. Double click the batch file to build it.

TopMost.exe set a window on top or not

```
 Echo TopMost.bat
 @Echo Off
 Echo This file compiles TopMost.vb to TopMost.exe
 Echo TopMost.exe set a window on top or not
 Echo To use 
 Echo     TopMost Top ^<windowtitle^>
 Echo     TopMost Not ^<windowtitle^>
 Echo E.G.
 Echo     TopMost Top Untitled - Notepad
 Echo -----------------------------------------------------
 "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\vbc.exe" /target:winexe /out:"%~dp0\TopMost.exe" "%~dp0\TopMost.vb" 
 pause
```

---

```
'TopMost.vb
Imports System
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
Imports Microsoft.Win32

Public Module TopMost
   Public Declare UNICODE Function FindWindowW Lib "user32" (ByVal lpClassName As String, ByVal lpWindowName As String) As IntPtr
   Public Declare Function SetWindowPos Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As IntPtr, ByVal hWndInsertAfter As Integer, ByVal x As Integer, ByVal y As Integer, ByVal cx As Integer, ByVal cy As Integer, ByVal wFlags As Integer) As Integer
   Public Const HWND_TOPMOST = -1
   Public Const SWP_NOMOVE = &H2
   Public Const SWP_NOSIZE = &H1
   Public Const HWND_NOTOPMOST = -2


 Sub Main()
    On Error Resume Next
    Dim hWindows as IntPtr
    Dim CmdLine as String
    Dim Ret as Integer
    CmdLine = Mid(Command(),5)
    hwindows = FindWindowW(vbNullString, CmdLine)
    If hwindows = 0 then
       Msgbox(Cmdline & " cannot be found.")
    Else
       If LCase(Left(Command(), 3)) = LCase("Top") then
          Ret = SetWindowPos(hwindows, HWND_TOPMOST, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_NOMOVE + SWP_NOSIZE)
          If Ret = 0 Then MsgBox("Set Pos Error is " & Err.LastDllError)
       ElseIf LCase(Left(Command(), 3)) = LCase("Not") then
          Ret = SetWindowPos(hwindows, HWND_NOTOPMOST, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_NOMOVE + SWP_NOSIZE)
           If Ret = 0 Then MsgBox("Set Pos Error is " & Err.LastDllError)
       Else
          Msgbox("Command line not recognised")
       End If
    End If
 End Sub
End Module
```